# How can use Noty package with laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5, noty

I have use a session like below in my controller

```
Session::flash('success', 'Profile updataed');
```

and i have import below files

```
use Illuminate\Session\flash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

and I have run npm install noty command

in my assets folder bootstrap.js file i have include

```
require('noty');
```

and after that I have add below script code in my main layout file

```
<script>
        @if(Session::has('success'))
            noty([
                type: 'success',
                layout: 'top',
                text: '{{ Session::get('success') }}'
                ]);
        @endif
    </script>
```

but its not giving me a notification what did i do wrong

Answer (score 0):

the noty [docs](https://ned.im/noty/#/options) suggest you create a notification like

```
new Noty({
    ...
    text: 'Some notification text',
    ...
}).show();
```